# What is the best practice to refresh accessory types in a UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm working on an universal app with the last UISplitViewController instance (post iOS8, working on both iPhone and iPad)

Apple bests practices says that on a simple table view, opening a new details view, you should show a disclosure indicator BUT that when your splitview is shown on an iPad, you should show no accessory to the master's tableview.

So i came up with this code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function :

```
cell.accessoryType = self.splitViewController!.collapsed ? .DisclosureIndicator : .None;
```

This works well, but some time, the splitviewcontroller changes, for example on iPhone 6 plus, when you rotate your device, or on iPad, when you use multitasking split-screen feature, the masters table view should hide or show again the accessory view, (and it does for new loaded cells like it should), but I would need to reload the whole tableview.

For now, I haven't found a function that trigger after the view changed his layout, to trigger my `tableview.reloadData()`.

Can someone tell me was is the best practice to reload my tableview and make sure the accessory changes like it should for all cells when my splitview layout changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect that the split view is collapsing or splitting by implementing the split view delegate methods in your split view controller class. Requires you to create a custom class for your split view controller. Not sure this buys you much as the delegates will probably get called before the split happens, so you cannot trigger a table load at that point as it will pick up the existing split not the split being moved to.

Better might be to detect that orientation has changed by registering for a notification. The good thing with the notification is that it is sent after the rotation has happened, so the new orientation is set. Then just reload and your existing cell creation code will do the rest.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // Add notification of orientation change
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "controllerRotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
 }

func controllerRotated(){
  if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){
     NSLog("Landscape")
  }
  else{
     NSLog("Portrait")
  }

  self.tableView.reloadData()        
}
```

Comment: Thats nice, it works for the orientation changes, but it won't work for iPad when i use the multitasking split-app on iPad. It returns on an iPhone layout, and the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification is not called when you start a multitasking interface on iPad. I will look for a notification for a change in layout in the apple docs, but I do like the way you do it !

Comment: i also added a `viewWillTransitionToSize` instance. Somehow, it wasn't working by itself, but side by side with your solution I cover all of my use cases !

Comment: @Dean The problem I found with the size transition was that this is called before the transition happens. However it looks like that method passes you a UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator into which you can register a block to run on transition completion. I would have a shot at calling reload from that block. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator/notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock: